# how to pull strings from a text file into a spreadsheet as labeled variables

Tags: regex, excel, ocr

I am a non-tech worker in the medical field trying to minimize transcription errors. I don't know where to start and was hoping people could point me in the right direction.  I will try to concisely summarize the process and describe what is needed:
A machine scans a person's eyes and outputs measurement data as a printout with clearly-printed text; this printout is scanned and uploaded into the system as a PNG.  I can download and run the PNG through an open-source OCR program and obtain a text file with line breaks, with most text in the original printout being correctly read.  The next step is to extract certain lines or phrases in this data and transcribe them into fields on a particular website.  As an intermediate step, however, it would be great to just get them into an excel file as labeled variables or with data labels, as this would allow someone to quickly copy/paste them into the appropriate fields on the website.

I know a little VBA coding and I'm at least familiar with the concept of regex pattern matching, but I'm not a programmer.  I did not see a way to attach files on this forum, but I can post an example of the output data text file and a guide I typed that describes exactly which pieces of information (18 variables total) I would like to pull from the data set.

Any and all feedback is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any sample data in your post. If you would have included I might have been able to provide an exact answer.
When performing Repetitive tasks like this you’re better off using get and transform than vba.
Go to data tab->get and transform ribbon->get data-> import csv.
The hard part will be making all the necessary changes but once you do it through the window for get and transform if the file is a repetitive file that require similar logic based steps you  won’t have to go through the cleanin data process again.

Comment: Can you message me so I can send you the data file example?

Comment: @Vanadium Im not entirely sure you can do that here. I googled and was unable to find a way. Worst case could you post a sample in the comment section or maybe this is too complex? Worst case you can send a file to meramoises@yahoo.com and if the file size is too large you can use WeTransfer website for larger file size. I have worked on issues similar to yours in the past and believe i may have a solution